# Trying to load a custom dataset in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, dataset, pytorch

I'm just starting out with PyTorch and am, unfortunately, a bit confused when it comes to using my own training/testing image dataset for a custom algorithm. For starters, I am making a small "hello world"-esque convolutional shirt/sock/pants classifying network. I've only loaded a few images and am just making sure that PyTorch can load them and transform them down properly to 32x32 usable images. My ImageFolder is set up like so:

> imgs/socks/*sockimages*.jpeg
>   imgs/pants/*pantsimages*.jpeg
>   imgs/shirt/*shirtimages*.jpeg

and a similar setup for my testing images folder. According to my current knowledge, the image loader built into PyTorch should read the labels from the subfolder names within the training/test images. However, I'm getting a `TypeError` complaining that my iterator is not iterable. Here's my code and the error:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.datasets as dset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

transform = transforms.Compose(
[transforms.ToTensor(),
 transforms.Scale((32,32)),
 transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = dset.ImageFolder(root="imgs",transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,shuffle=True,         num_workers=2)

testset = dset.ImageFolder(root='tests',transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,shuffle=True,     num_workers=2)

classes=('shirt','pants','sock')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# functions to show an image
def imshow(img):
    img = img / 2 + 0.5     # unnormalize
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))

# get some random training images
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()

# show images
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images))
# print labels
print(' '.join('%5s' % classes[labels[j]] for j in range(4)))
```

## Error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

It says that it is in reference to the line containing `dataiter.next()`, meaning that the compiler believes that I cannot iterate `dataiter`?

Please help! Thanks in advance,

-David Sillman, new to PyTorch

Answer (score 5):

I think the error comes because in the `transform.Compose` you are doing first `.ToTensor()` and, instead, you should do `.Scale()`. `Pytorch` has transformations on **tensors** and on **PIL Images**, that are *not* interchangeable.
Reading the docs it says

> class torchvision.transforms.Scale(size, interpolation=2) [...]
>    Rescale the input PIL.Image to the given size.

While you are changing that image to a Pytorch tensor before scaling thus making it crash.

It should be changed to:

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
                   [transforms.Scale((32,32)),
                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

You will get this error when applying `PIL Image` transformations on tensors.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, I think `transforms.ToTensor()` before `transform.Scale((32, 32))` is not right.

In the document of `Scale::__call__(self, img)` already show

> Args: img(PIL.Image): Image to be scaled.

So the input for `Scale` is `PIL.Image` not `Tensor`.

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
[transforms.ToTensor(),
 transforms.Scale((32,32)),
 transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

So you could try the following one:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Scale((32,32)),
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 
                                                     (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

You can the script to load your custom dataset at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/xpzouying/8078000043a0713056ba14490a90807b). Click [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xpzouying/animals-classification/master/images/gist1.png) to the result of the script.

I post the full classification in custom images, you could check it at **github.com/xpzouying/animals-classification**

Comment: In the future, the [transforms.Scale() class  will be deprecated](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Scale)  in favor of `transform.Resize()` class.

Answer (score 0):

This might be as simple as you not providing the correct path to the "imgs" folder.  Are you running your program from the same folder as the "imgs" folder?  Try specifying an absolute path to your "imgs" folder and see if it helps.

Comment: This didn't work. If that were even the case, it would've said that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: Hmm do you get the same error if you instead try 

`images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))`

Comment: I unfortunately still get the same uniterable builtin method/function error. I have no idea what's causing this phenomenon. Is it happening for you?

Comment: I haven't tried running your code but saw something similar in my case a while ago. The problem seems to be that the trainloader you're passing in isn't what you expect it to be (in my case a similar issue arose when I was passing in the dataset itself instead of the trainloader). Have you tried printing the internals of the trainloader object to see if it contains the expected data?